# Bidimensional heat equation for $f(x,y)=1$ if $y\leq x$ and $0$ otherwise

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I've been solving some problems from my Partial Differential Equations course, and found a particular case that gives me a situation that my course notes don't explain. The problem was the following:

> Solve the following bidimensional heat equation:
>
> $$ \left. \begin{array}{rrlcl}
>       \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} & = & \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} & , & 0<x<1,\phantom{a}
>  0<y<1,\phantom{a}t>0   \\ u(x,y,0) & = & f(x,y) & , & \text{(starting
>  heat of the surface)}   \\ u(0,y,t) = u(1,y,t) & = & 0 & , & 0\leq
>  y\leq 1, \phantom{a} t\geq0    \\ u(x,0,t) = u(x,1,t) & = & 0 & , &
>  0\leq x\leq 1, \phantom{a} t\geq 0 \end{array} \right\} $$
>
> where $f(x,y)$ equals $1$ if $y\leq x$ and $0$ otherwise.

In my course notes, the way to solve this kind of problem (it's based on the variable separation method) is by finding the values of $A_{m,n}$ and $\lambda_{m,n}$ for the solution expression (in this particular problem, $a=b=c=1$):
$$u(x,y,t)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum^\infty_{m=1}A_{m,n}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{b}\right)e^{-\lambda^2_{m,n}t},$$
where their values are defined by the expressions:
$$A_{m,n}=\frac{4}{ab}\int_0^b\int_0^af(x,y)\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{b}\right)dxdy,$$
$$\lambda_{m,n}=c\pi\sqrt{\frac{m^2}{a^2}+\frac{n^2}{b^2}}.$$

Here's where my problem is. I've calculated the value of $A_{m,n}$ (both by hand and also using Mathematica) and this is what I got:
$$A_{m,n}=\frac{4((-1)^{1+m}m^2+(-1)^{m+n}m^2-n^2+(-1)^mn^2)}{mn(m^2-n^2)\pi^2}.$$

**My drawback:**

As you may guess, the problem is in the $(m^2-n^2)$ that appears in the denominator, because it makes $A_{m,m}$ undefined $\forall m\in\mathbb N$. If tried simplifying the expression and could not, I also tried finding the limit when $m$ goes to $n$ but didn't work either. My couse notes don't say anything about this happening and it's the only example which I've seen with such a denominator (they usually just have powers of $m,n$ and $\pi$, but no things that make the denominator $0$ for natural values of $m,n$).

**My question:**

What's the problem here? What can I do to solve this problem? Is there some condition a problem must verify in order to be solvable by this method that this one doesn't have?

Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: So you just want to know $\int_{0}^{1}\left( \int_{0}^{x} \sin(n\pi x)\sin(n\pi y)\,dy\right)dx$?

Comment: @Ali no, I know what that integral is, it's what I calculated. My problem is the denominator, it's a particular case that my notes don't study and don't know what to do.

Comment: What are you talking about? Your integral contains both $m$s and $n$s.

Comment: Well anyway I don't see a problem with zero denominators here
\begin{eqnarray}
  \int_{0}^{1} \left( \int_{0}^{x} \sin\left(n\pi y\right)dy\right)\sin\left(n\pi x\right)dx
&=&\frac{1}{n\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \big(1-\cos\left(n\pi x\right)\big) \sin\left(n\pi x\right)dx\\
&=& \frac{1}{n\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \left(\sin(n\pi x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2n\pi x)\right)dx\\
&=& -\frac{1}{(n\pi)^{2}}\big[\cos(n\pi x)\big]_{0}^{1}+
\frac{1}{(2n\pi)^{2}}\big[\cos(2n\pi x)\big]_{0}^{1}\\
&=&\begin{cases}2/(n\pi)^{2} &\text{for }n\text{ odd}\\
  0 & \text{for }n\text{ even}
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @Ali no, you read it wrong. There's no $\sin(n\pi x)$ in my expression, it's $\sin(m\pi x)$. You changed the $m$ and put an $n$ instead.

Comment: I put $m=n$ because you explicitly ask for the case $m=n$. Read your own question. You ask for help evaluating $A_{m,m}$.

Comment: @Ali Excuse me, my bad, you're totally correct. I was the one misundertanding. I can do it properly now, thank you very much for your answer and forgive me.